# Converting Binary Linked List Into It's Equivalent Decimal Number

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I want to convert a binary linked list, with each node containing a single bit, into it's decimal equivalent. Example:

```
Input  : 0->0->0->1->1->0->0->1->0
Output : 50
```

I found a code online to solve this problem but I am having difficulty in understanding a particular line.

```
/* Returns decimal value of binary linked list */
int decimalValue(struct Node *head)
{
    // Initialized result
    int  res = 0;

    // Traverse linked list
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        // Multiply result by 2 and add
        // head's data
        res = (res  << 1) + head->data;

        // Move next
        head = head->next;
    }
    return res;
}
```

I am unable to understand the use of `re = (res << 1) + head->data`in this code. I mean how is it multiplying 2 in this line? Can anyone please tell me this lines function and show it's working ?

Comment: It is shifting `res` left by one bit and adding the `data` field of the `head`. Actually there is a comment explaining this. Are you sure this is the only line you don't understand?

Comment: `res = (res  << 1) + head->data;` does what the comment says "Multiply result by 2 and add head's data".  What about the comment is not clear?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am not that familiar with the shift operators so I am unable to understand how 2 was multiplied in that expression? Can you please explain it with sample data?

Comment: @chux I am unable to understand how 2 get's multiplied in that line.

Comment: Do you understand how shifting of a decimal number by one decimal place multiplies it by 10?

Comment: @EugeneSh. As I already said I am not familiar with shift operators. I have never used them in any programs. Please just show me 1 example how is it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res  << 1` shifts the bit pattern of `res` to the "left" (more significant digits).

As integers are store in memory using binary notation, shifting left doubles the number - same as `res * 2`.

```
    MSbit         LSbit
    v                 v
    0000 1111 0011 0011  or  3891
    shifted left
    0001 1110 0110 0110  or  7782
```

`res << 1` works just like  `res * 2` when there is no overflow nor negative numbers involved.

For OP's  purpose, the below are the same.

```
res = (res << 1) + head->data;
res = (res * 2) + head->data;
```

In either case, robust code would watch out for overflow.

```
if (res > INT_MAX/2) { puts("Overflow"); exit(-1) }
res = (res * 2) + head->data;
...
```

Comment: Check this article -> https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-binary-number-in-a-linked-list-to-integer/solutions/629087/detailed-explanation-java-faster-than-100-00/

Answer (score 0):

Think of it visually -- inside each loop iteration, you're pushing all of the bits to the left, opening up a new slot.  Then, the addition operator is filling that slot on the right.

Comment: Ok, got that. But how is it multiplying 2 by doing this? It's written in the comment that it is multiplying 2 and adding head's data to it and storing it in res

Comment: While working in binary, shifting left by one is the same as if you multiplied the number by 2.

Let's have an example.  Take the number 3, decimal.  In binary, it's 11.  If you multiply 3 by 2, you get 6.  In binary, it's 110.   If you break apart the binary digits, 110 is 4 plus 2 plus zero.

In base-10 (normal decimal arithmetic), shifting left by one is the same as multiplying by 10.